# How to trim the left and right white spaces when a table is previewed?

Tags: preview

The following table has unwanted right and left white spaces. But you cannot see them because the figure has been converted to PNG with alpha channel enabled.

How to trim the left and right white spaces when a table is previewed?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,array}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\PreviewEnvironment{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{*3{m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth/3\relax}}}
        \toprule
        Unit & Macro & Symbol\\
        \midrule
        ampere & \verb|\ampere| & \si{\ampere}\\
        candela & \verb|\candela|& \si{\candela}\\
        kelvin & \verb|\kelvin|& \si{\kelvin}\\
        kilogram & \verb|\kilogram|& \si{\kilogram}\\
        meter & \verb|\meter|& \si{\meter}\\
        mole & \verb|\mole|& \si{\mole}\\
        second & \verb|\second|& \si{\second}\\
        \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Note that I am not talking about the white spaces that can be removed by `@{}`s. The unwanted white spaces can be understood if  you compile my MWE.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I would suggest using an `s` coulmn for the units. You might also want to define a function which prints the name and the unit, as I do in the `siunitx` manual, to avoid repeating material in your source.

Comment: @JosephWright: I agree. I am very keen on applying the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) philosophy to my daily projects. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Implicit change from `longtable` to `tabular`

In simple cases, where the use of `longtable` does not contain more than `tabular` would allow, the `longtable` environment could be redefined to be a `tabular` environment:

```
\ifPreview
  \let\longtable\tabular
  \let\endlongtable\endtabular
\fi
\PreviewEnvironment{longtable}
```

Anyway, the `longtable` is not broken across pages, when taken as preview element.
Also other features of `longtable` will not work, e.g. `\endfoot`.

### Adjusting `\hsize`

The `longtable` environment sets chunks with width `\hsize`, filled left with `\LTleft` and on the right side with `\LTright`. The widths of the columns are remembered in the `.aux` file. The latter data can be used to calculate the width of the table.
Then `\hsize` is set to the total width. `\linewidth` can remain unchanged, it is not used in `longtable`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,array}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt

\makeatletter
\ifPreview
  \newcommand*{\SetLongtableWidth}{%
    \begingroup
      \edef\@ltnum{\@roman\numexpr\value{LT@tables}+1}%
      \@ifundefined{LT@\@ltnum}{%
        \gdef\@ltwidth{0pt}%
      }{%
        \def\LT@entry##1##2{+##2}%
        \xdef\@ltwidth{\the\dimexpr 0pt\csname LT@\@ltnum\endcsname}%
      }%
    \endgroup
    \ifdim\@ltwidth>\z@
      \hsize=\@ltwidth\relax
    \fi
  }%
  \newcommand{\org@longtable}{}%
  \let\org@longtable\longtable
  \def\longtable{\SetLongtableWidth\org@longtable}%
\fi
\makeatother

\PreviewEnvironment{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{*3{m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth/3\relax}}}
        \toprule
        Unit & Macro & Symbol\\
        \midrule
        ampere & \verb|\ampere| & \si{\ampere}\\
        candela & \verb|\candela|& \si{\candela}\\
        kelvin & \verb|\kelvin|& \si{\kelvin}\\
        kilogram & \verb|\kilogram|& \si{\kilogram}\\
        meter & \verb|\meter|& \si{\meter}\\
        mole & \verb|\mole|& \si{\mole}\\
        second & \verb|\second|& \si{\second}\\
        \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add @{} on each side of your table (skipping the header) :

```
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}*3{m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth/3\relax}}@{}}
\toprule
etc.
\midrule
etc
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The unwanted white spaces I am talking about are not what you said above.